# navigation view android not triggered onOptionsItemSelected on R.id.home

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have created the navigation drawer activity from android studio and in the method `onOptionsItemSelected` i'm trying to catch the click of the hamburger icon but it doesn't work.
The only thing i changed is this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            Log.w("ACTIVITY","home pressed");
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```